# PHP Template Engine and CMS

Tags: php, wordpress, drupal, content-management-system, template-engine

I developed a dynamic website using PHP and MySQL. Right now I'm considering switching to a CM` such as WordPress or Drupal. I also heard something about PHP template engine. Could anyone give me some insights on the pros and cons of PHP template, and a CMS?

If you recommend a CMS, which one do you suggest?

Comment: PHP is a template engine to begin with, So you want to do templates for your templating engine so you can template while templating? Yo dawg...

Comment: Also depends on what you want to do. If your website can be put into a blog/page-format, Wordpress is good, if it is more Wiki-like, Drupal is probably good, ... it's more a question of what you are most familiar/comfortable with and what fits your website format best.

Comment: My website is to allow users to fill in some information and display in a fixed format in user dashboard. Basically to let them create their own page by filling in their own content such as setting profile image, upload images to display in gallery, and there will be a comment page for user page.

Comment: I'd suggest moving to a PHP framework like CodeIgniter or Yii etc and use a templating engine either from the framework or a standalone like Smarty. This will cover most of the functionality you need and sort your code out into something more management (MVC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're talking about a template engine, all this means is subdividing PHP which will be reused into separate files and then including them in other files where they are needed. This is useful when you have headers and footers on your website that will remain the same (or almost the same) site-wide.

Content management systems are really great when you're making websites for a person with little or no programming knowledge.  Personally, I use [WordPress](http://wordpress.org); I find it's the easiest CMS to learn and also has the largest community of developers. Other CMS's are Drupal, and Joomla! I prefer not to use Drupal or Joomla! because I'm not as comfortable, but I suppose it's up to the situation provided and up to the developer's desire.

Comment: I did try out wordpress by setting up a personal blog on wordpress.com. Switching from my current php site to CMS is load of works since I have lots functions I created in php, JQuery, and Ajax. My goal is to make Admin's job easier to maintain the data and registered users, and also providing a user friendly UI to registered users.

Comment: based on this, I'd suggest you to build the application on scratch and use some popular template engines like Smarty since you can reuuse the html markup you might have already created. And don't forget to give @cereallarceny some credit, since the user perfectly answered your initial question.

Comment: @user1301840 - you should still be able to mark him as answered surely?

Answer (score 2):

I think that author was talking about template engines like SMARTY or OPT. I prefere SMARTY, but there is more of them. Quite similiar to each other, and that a good thing cause switching isn't hard. They are usefull when You have people for development and people for design, cause one work with files for logic, and another work with files for design. Or if You learned programming on languages like C#, or similiar where You have big and complex visual side of application (WPF).

For the CMS systems. I write sometimes my own, or I use Wordpress (really nice), or Drupal, or work with some kind of framework Kohana, or Symphony. Really depends of situation. There is no golden idea for that. Maybe more precise question would help to answer.

Comment: I really don't know much about Template Engines. I just looked it up on youtube and got some basic ideas. It's just that I have to switch to a CMS eventually due to the growing of users. It would be hard to maintain the information. I wonder if any of those I put in the question would contribute in easing website development along the way.

Comment: Have to say that if You are a skilled programmer then only template engine you need, and no CMS, cause when You will need something from CMS you will just write it. There is a drawback in case of CMS, they have some limitation, and to resolve some problems You will have to search tons of material to get it done good. When You have you own system, You know what is going where, and when You write it You know what kind of functions You need.
YouTube is not a good idea for learning such things. I would go to bookstore buy one or two books about it and be friend with official documentation.

Answer (score 2):

First off, if you use a cms you will be using a template system.  It just happens to be the template system provided by the cms.

The big 2 php based cms systems are Joomla and Drupal. Then there are the blogs, of which the most heavily used is wordpress.

Whether you would be better off with a blog or a cms depends a lot on the type of site you're developing, although it's possible to build a complete site with either type of platform.

In just about every case there is a substantial learning curve to these systems, especially if you intend to extend them, or implement your own template from scratch.  However, one advantage to using a popular cms or blog package is that there are marketplaces where you can buy pre-made templates for relatively little money, that you can then tweak without having to indoctrinate yourself.

I highly recommend you spend some time exploring the packages at http://www.opensourcecms.com/, which has demos of all the systems available to play with.

Comment: Currently, I have my own design, so I wouldn't wanna get someone else's. So do you think it's better to make my own template for CMS?

Comment: It's really just a question of learning their template system and how their menu system works, but there is no reason you can't develop your own template.  You just might want to try and find one that is close to yours, but with that said, they all have existing templates you can learn from, and usually there are solid tutorials and documentation on how to develop a template from scratch.